# Android Background is showing in the graphical layout but not on the device

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot see what the issue is. I am using eclipse 4.2.2. My SDK is fully updated.

When I set an application background in Android, it shows up on the graphical layout but not on the device. I have made a few apps that do nothing but display images or text on a single activity. Some of them will display the background using the same image that others wont. But in all cases it shows up in the graphical layout.

What are some common causes for this?

I am very much a beginner. 
Thank you VERY much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a very common problem.update your manifest file.Check whether you have used

try build the project using that sdk version and open up the avd using that particular api.All images will be shown.

Comment: Can you share your XML snippet the part where you are setting this background.